# Cron job in lambda in Node.js

Tags: node.js, lambda, cron

I created a lambda function with cron schedule but cron not starting.

```
var request = require('request');
var cron = require('node-cron');

const mysql = require('serverless-mysql')({
    config: {
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
    }
})



exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    
    task = cron.schedule('*/5 * * * *', () =>  {
            console.log('started..')
    }, {
      scheduled: false
    });

    task.start();   
    
    return {status:"SUCCESS"};
}
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Can you point to the documentation you are following? If you are running on AWS then I assume your lambda needs a trigger of some kind. CloudWatch has a cron trigger - could you use that?

Comment: Why don't you use aws glue instead? You can set a schedule pretty easily in glue. Also, it should be fairly easy to setup db connection assuming your db is in aws.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a cron schedule inside the lambda. Which event will trigger this lambda?

Even if you trigger the lambda, lambda will NOT maintain any state between the executions. This is not how AWS Lambda works.

I assume that you want to execute lambda based on some cron schedule. If that is the case, you can create event rule using AWS EventBridge and then can trigger the lambda based on the cron schedule in the event rule.

I've written a detailed step-by-step article here - https://www.cloudtechsimplified.com/run-cron-jobs-in-lambda/

Hope this helps!